# What is maximum of RAM and EEPROM use for Z80

Tags: memory, memory-management, ram, eeprom, z80

I don't understand how function memory adress so i whant to buy memory for my zilog z80 but I don't know whitch one. I whant to know the maximum of memory can be using  whith Zilog Z80.

Comment: why don't just read the datasheet? A simple Google search shows that Z80 uses 16-bit address which means it can have at most 64KB of RAM

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't about programming

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming.

Answer (score 2):

The Z80 has a 16bit address bus, therefore it can only address at most 64KB of memory.
It also has a separate I/O control line, which means that bank switching circuitry can be implemented so that the maximum usable memory is increased beyond this limit.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bank_switching